# SimpleCusorAdapter empty when using it with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm using a SimpleCusorAdapter to populate data into a ListView and the problem is : **When I install the app for the first time I get a empty list like this**

[image: this]

When I launch the app for the second time data are normally populated in the ListView like

[image: this]

I checked my code and I don't see the cause of that, do you see it ? Or any other ideas to solve this ?

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.sample.mchquiz;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private Spinner spinner1;
    private ListView listViewCategories;
    private QuestionBank questionBank = new QuestionBank();
    private int userId;
    private EditText idkey;
    private Button buttonAdd;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private Button btn;
    private TextView categoryChooseTxt;
    public static String cat;
    public void setCat(String cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }

    private QuestionBank mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionBank();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_example);
        ListView questionList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.questionList);
        MyDataBaseHelper dbhelper = new MyDataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String choosedLevel = intent.getStringExtra("level");
        Cursor questions = dbhelper.getAllCategoriesByLevelCursor(choosedLevel);
        String[] from = new String[] {"category"};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.question_entry};
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_example_entry, questions, from, to);
        Log.v("Cursor", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(questions));
        new MyCustomAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();

        questionList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        questionList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor selectedItemCursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String selectedItem = selectedItemCursor.getString(selectedItemCursor.getColumnIndex("category"));
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), quiz.class);
                intent2.putExtra("cat", selectedItem);
                setCat(selectedItem);
                System.out.println("ID is: " + view.getId());
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        });

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9438613237055579~8907320992");


    }

    private void setupButton(ArrayList<String> catList) {

        Context newContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(getBaseContext(), R.style.buttonMainActivityWithMargin);

        for (int i= 0; i< catList.size(); i++) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutCategories);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 5);
            btn = new Button(newContext, null, R.style.button_learn);
            btn.setText(catList.get(i));
            btn.setId(i);
            btn.setContentDescription(catList.get(i));
            btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            btn.setEms(10);
            btn.setTextSize(20);
            btn.setPadding(10,10,10,10  );
            layout.addView(btn, layoutParams);
            btn.setOnClickListener(myButtonClickHandler);
        }

    }

    View.OnClickListener myButtonClickHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), quiz.class);
            intent2.putExtra("selectedId", view.getId());
            String buttonText = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
            intent2.putExtra("cat", buttonText);
            setCat(String.valueOf(((Button) view).getText()));
            System.out.println("ID is: " + view.getId());
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    };


    public class MyCustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        private Context context;
        ProgressDialog proDia;
        public MyCustomAsyncTask(Context context){
            this.context=context;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            proDia = new ProgressDialog(context);
            proDia.setTitle("Loading");
            proDia.setMessage("Please wait");
            //proDia.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            proDia.setMax(10);
            proDia.setProgress(0);
            proDia.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                mQuestionLibrary.initQuestions(getApplicationContext());
            return true;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
            if(proDia.isShowing()) proDia.dismiss();
            proDia = null;


        }
    }
}
```

**MyDataBaseHelper.java**

```
public Cursor getAllCategoriesByLevelCursor(String level) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT id as _id, category FROM " + TABLE_QUESTION + " WHERE LEVEL = '" + level + "' GROUP BY category";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;

}
```

**QuestionBank.java**

public void initQuestions(Context context) {

```
    myDataBaseHelper = new MyDataBaseHelper(context);

    category = MainActivity.cat;

    list = myDataBaseHelper.getAllQuestionsList(category);//get questions/choices/answers from database


    if (list.isEmpty()) {//if list is , populate database with default questions/choices/answers

        myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("A1", "Im 4. Stock steht ein ... Fahrrad.", new String[]{"teuer", "teures", "teurer", "teure"}, "teures", "Adjektiv - Deklination (''der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee'')"));
        myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("A1", "Ein ... T-Shirt hängt im 2. Stock.", new String[]{"langweilige", "langweiliges", "langweiliger", "langweilig"}, "langweiliges", "Adjektiv - Deklination (''der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee'')"));
        myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("A1", "Schau mal! Dort ist ein ... Sessel.", new String[]{"unbequemer", "unbequemes", "unbequeme", "unbequem"}, "unbequemer", "Adjektiv - Deklination (''der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee'')"));
        myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("A1", "Im 1. Stock ist eine ... Einbauküche.", new String[]{"günstige", "günstiges", "günstiger", "günstig"}, "günstige", "Adjektiv - Deklination (''der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee'')"));
        myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("A1", "Hier ist eine ... Mikrowelle.", new String[]{"teuere", "teure", "teures", "teuer"}, "teure", "Adjektiv - Deklination (''der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee'')"));
        myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("A1", "Im Untergeschoss steht ein ... Stuhl.", new String[]{"altmodischer", "altmodisches", "altmodisch", "altmodische"}, "altmodischer", "Adjektiv - Deklination (''der kalte Kaffee/ein kalter Kaffee/kalter Kaffee'')"));
    myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("A2", "Leider kann ich euch morgen nur eine halbe Stunde besuchen. - Oh, schade, das ist nicht ... ." , new String[]{"kurz", "manchmal", "oft", "lange"}, "lange" , "Adverb - Temporaladverb (dann, später, nachher,..)"));
    myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("A2", "Mit dem neuen Auto fuhr Andreas nur ..., weil er schon nach kurzer Zeit einen schweren Unfall hatte." , new String[]{"zuerst", "ein paar Wochen", "oft", "nie"}, "ein paar Wochen" , "Adverb - Temporaladverb (dann, später, nachher,..)"));
    myDataBaseHelper.addInitialQuestion(new Question("A2", "\"Christophs neue CD ist ein Hit, man hört sie ________ im Radio.\"" , new String[]{"später", "schließlich", "ständig", "nie"}, "" , "Adverb - Temporaladverb (dann, später, nachher,..)"));
    list = myDataBaseHelper.getAllQuestionsList(category);//get list from database again

}
```

}

Comment: `mQuestionLibrary.initQuestions(getApplicationContext());` ??

Comment: `intent.getStringExtra("level");` are you sure this actually returns a valid `chosenLevel`, every time the app is launched?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I added the initQuestions method, I'm using it to populate my questions

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran yes I've tested it and it returns the correct level

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh now edited

Comment: first time , you fill your database with data and after that you are fetching it next time and you are not using `list` first time anywhere which has the data first time

Comment: yes you're right ! thanks a lot